# Removing Extra WCF namespace from WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I am having problems in working with the Namespaces in the WCF. I have never done it before. I have tried a lot to find solution on the google. But still I am not able to find a solution for it.

I have written a WCF service which is divided in 3 projects and additionally i have created a models project:

1. Contracts (ServiceContract)
2. Service (Codebehind)
3. Host (ServiceHost)
4. Models (DataContract classes)

When I am hosting the service in IIS, it is generating the WSDL fine but there are namespaces which I have not defined as below:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/
http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Models
```

The problem is that I want to access all my service contracts and data contracts through same namespace only.

Because when the `DataContract` classes are generated in the proxy class, it is being duplicated. Mean if I have a class `ClassA` in my `Models` projects, then it is giving me 2 classes as `ClassA` and `ClassA1`.

I saw that in proxy class that these are there in the different namespace. So, I want to avoid that.

I also want to avoid `ChannelFactory` method, because there are a lot of `OperationContract` functions. So, don't want to  code that much with hand but would like it to be auto generated in right fashion.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean regarding `ChannelFactory` method and having a lot of hand coding.  `ChannelFactory` will generate the proxy for you - there is nothing to code by hand outside of the creation of the factory and getting a channel from it.

Comment: Yes - the namespace of your server-side service objects, and your client-side proxy-generated objects, typically *are* different - **unless** you know that you control both ends of the service call (server + client), and you can put your data contracts into a *separate assembly* that is referenced by both the server and the client. In that case, the data classes exist **only once** in your data contract assembly.

Comment: Have you defined the namespaces for your contract/service?

Comment: *Because when the DataContract classes are generated in the proxy class, it is being duplicated. Mean if I have a class ClassA in my Models projects, then it is giving me 2 classes as ClassA and ClassA1.* - can you post the code where this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also want to avoid ChannelFactory method, because there are a lot of
>   OperationContract functions. So, don't want to code that much with
>   hand but would like it to be auto generated in right fashion.

This makes no sense at all. The `ChannelFactory<T>.CreateInstance()` method is much lighter than a wsdl-generated service proxy, and the amount of code you will have to write is comparible.

Service references are designed for when you're calling third party services which you have no control over or internal visability of.

There is aboslutely no situation I can think of where using a generated service reference is preferable to using ChannelFactory if you have access to the service definition assemblies.

This is especially the case for your requirement to manipulate the service wsdl in order to control code generation on the client side.